# Should I register every time before uploading to pypi?

Tags: python, pypi

I know this is what it needs to publish your project to pypi

```
$ python setup.py register -r pypi 
$ python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi 
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r pypi
```

Should I register every time before uploading to pypi? Or just the first time? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I can confirm the answer is: **Yes, always**

If you don't register, pypi will not allow you to upload. And you can't register with the same version number, this is not allowed either, which means you should modify version number in `setup.py` before registering and uploading.

What if I don't want to change version but need to modify code?
Here's a solution:
Suppose the previous version is `0.0.1`, then you can use `0.0.1.post1` and pypi will happily accept this.

Here's `0.0.1.post1` version of my ezcf package on pypi, as you can see it is a valid version number.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezcf/0.0.1.post1

Answer (score 0):

Only the first time is needed for each repository (`-r`) that you push to.

Edit: **However** if you update metadata (i.e. anything in `setup.py`) you should re-register your package. Also, if you happen to use the testing server (`-r test`), this server is cleaned periodically so you should re-register every time you use it.

Comment: So after that I only need to do `sdist upload` and `bdist_wheel upload` if I have a new version?

Comment: @laike9m Yes. Version changes should be picked up automatically. However see my edits for a few exceptions I just remembered.

Comment: If I register again, is there going to be more than one version on pypi? I'm worried about this...

Comment: My guess is no (though I've never tried it). From [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/packageindex.html#pypi-overview): "PyPI holds a record for each (name, version) combination submitted." So if you re-register with the same name/version, it should just update the existing record.